# ASP.MVC DropDownListFor Default Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to generate a dropdownlist in my view, like the one below except I want my option label (`"Please select..."`) to have a value of -1 as blank is already occupied by another option. Is there anyway to do this without adding it to the select list in my controller or view model, or creating a new html helper?

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.stuff.Id, new SelectList(Model.stuff, "Id", "Name"), "Please select...")%>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want my option label ("Please select...") to have a value of -1

You cannot do this out of the box with the DropDownListFor helper. It will always use blank for this value. You have two possibilities:

1. Write a custom helper
2. Add it manually to the collection

Actually you have a third possibility which IMHO is the best and what I would recommend you:

Don't use blank as values. This should be reserved for the *Please Select* default value. It doesn't seem logical to use blank as the value of something that the user can actually select. You might also have problems with the validation.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I suspected. This is a one of case so I think I will go with the latter

Comment: RE: your last comment, totally with you this one. However this is a particular case and after consideration using blank as a selectable value makes other things a lot simpler.

Comment: To expand on option #2, the accepted answer for this post gives a good idea how to implement it: http://forums.asp.net/t/1572194.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Concat method to add a new item to the SelectList after you get your values from the database. Then set the value to 0 and text to "Please Select".

```
 var selectList = new SelectList(types.Concat( new[]{new MediaType() {MediaTypeId = 0, Type = "Please select"}})
            , "mediatypeid", "type");
```